# How to solve “A RenderFlex overflowed on the right.” error in Row?

Tags: flutter

I get the error on the Row widget.
How can I fix it?

[image]

```
Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Row( // error is shown on this line
          children: [
            const Image(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              image: NetworkImage(...),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 5.0,
                runSpacing: 5.0,
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  Text('Message:'),
                  Text('Hello world! How are you doing?'),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
),
```

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 16 pixels on the right.

Comment: use `Expanded` instead of `Wrap`? like `Expanded > Text`

Comment: @pskink there should be other text widgets also thats's why I used Wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expanded` Widget on top of `Padding` do the trick for you

```
Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Row(
              // error is shown on this line
              children: [
                Image(
                  height: 120,
                  width: 120,
                  image: NetworkImage(""),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Wrap(
                    spacing: 5.0,
                    runSpacing: 5.0,
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    children: [
                      Text('Message:'),
                      Text(
                          'Hello world! How are you doing?',),
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for a clue for these errors. Here 16px is trying to tell us about the issue. I did not try but I guess that padding causes this overflowing. Try to change padding like this:

```
Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Row( // error is shown on this line
          children: [
            const Image(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              image: NetworkImage(...),
            ),
            Padding(
              // Change this!
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,8,0,8),
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 5.0,
                runSpacing: 5.0,
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  Text('Hello world! How are you doing?'),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: that doesn't work. when the text line is wider the error arrises again